# Safely move CUPS spool directory

Tags: linux, redhat, cups

For scaling purposes we need to move the spool directory from cups from one partition to another on some hosts.

To keep the same configuration files across the whole pool of servers, we'll replace the old directory with a symbolic link.

My question is : Is it safe to move the directory without stopping cups server (that's production servers), or will it mess with cups/make some jobs be lost ?

If so, we'll have to schedule a maintenance period and that costs budget !

CUPS version : 1.1.17-13.3.16.el3

Comment: Didn't you try this in a lab first?

Comment: That's actually quite wise... I should be able to setup a lab with a loaded printer. But we'll just do the migration by night I guess. Thanks, I'll let you guys know what we get.